# Get the Source value in ConvertBack() method for IValueConverter implementation in WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I am binding a dependency property to textboxex in WPF. The property is a string that has some values separated by '/' (example: "1/2/3/4" ). I need to bind individual values to separate textboxes which is fine with following implementation of `Convert()` method:

```js
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
  {
    String[] data = (value as string).Split('/');
    return data[Int16.Parse(parameter as string)];
  }
  return String.Empty;
}
```

And I am using the `ConverterParameter` in `xaml` to specify the position of wanted value. 
However, the problem is with `ConvertBack()` method. I do not know, how to get the source value so I could just add or change just one value in the string (on the specified position).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you change the Property to a IList<string> instead?

Comment: I am using LINQ to SQL classes, I would probably have to change the generated code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, you can safely make `ConvertBack` just throw `NotImplementedException`.

Indeed, you just haven't got enough information to recreate the source value from its part!

If you really need the back conversion (e.g., if you use two-direction binding), I would split the property into 3 strings in the view model (the class used in `DataContext`), and bind to them separately.

Comment: It should not throw a `NotImplementedException` but rather a `NotSupportedException` as the method will never be implemented.

Comment: I do need to implement the method, because I am using TwoWay binding mode

Comment: @tom: then you should replace your dependency property with four ones, each representing a part of the string.

Comment: @Vlad: Well, the property is generated automatically when adding LINQ to SQL classes through a wizard in VS2010. It is associated with a column from database and that column contains values like "1/2/3/4". On top of that, I need to bind about 10 columns of this form

Comment: @tom: you can use an intermediate class which would provide the four properties, like this: http://pastebin.com/cLWAbLaC

Comment: @Vlad: Could you, please, provide a sample code how to use that class? Also the problem is, that there doesn't have to be just four values. Some columns have 3, some 4, some 5 values separated by '/'. I also need to ensure, that the changes are propagated to `DataContext` so I can call `DataContext.SubmitChanges()` to store data to the local database

Comment: @Vlad: thanks, but I don't see where you split the original string to get the individual values. Also, should'n it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @tom: split should be in the method `UpdateParts`. And you don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged`, since `First` etc. are dependency properties.

Comment: @Vlad: Ahaa, so it will also automatically update the original dependency property and I can call `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`? Is that right?

Comment: The code makes works this way: as soon as the original dependency property changes, the four parts are updated, too (inside of UpdateParts()). As soon as any of the four parts are updated (e.g., through the binding), the original dependency property is updated accordingly (inside of UpdateSource()).

Comment: Great, I guess I need to implement `GetValue()`, `SetValue()` and `UpdateParts()` right?

Comment: @Vlad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2493/discussion-between-tom-and-vlad)

Comment: @Vlad: oh, I am sorry, I just found out that LINQ to SQL wizard doesn't generate dependency properties, but properties for each column of the database tables that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface..any simple modification to your code to solve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: It should be not so complicated. Instead of subscribing for the changes on the dependency property, you should do it at INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

You have probably solved your issue already with the help of *Vlad*, I just thought I should add another way of actually getting the source value in the converter.

First you could make your converter derive from `DependencyObject` so you can add a Dependency Property to it which we shall bind to

```
public class MyConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static DependencyProperty SourceValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SourceValue",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(MyConverter));
    public string SourceValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SourceValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //...
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object targetValue = value;
        object sourceValue = SourceValue;
        //...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, a Converter doesn't have a `DataContext` so the Binding won't work out of the box but you can use Josh Smith's excellent `DataContextSpy`: [Artificial Inheritance Contexts in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx)

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <src:DataContextSpy x:Key="dataContextSpy" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="YourProperty"
                 ConverterParameter="1">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <src:MyConverter SourceValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataContextSpy},
                                                       Path=DataContext.YourProperty}"/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**End of Update**

Dr.WPF has an elegant solution to this, see the following thread
[The way to access binding source in ConvertBack()?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4365faf0-208b-479c-be3a-40e10aab0afa)

**Edit**

Using the solution by Dr.WPF, you could supply both the string index and the source `TextBox` to the converter with this (perhaps a little verbose) sample code

```
<TextBox dw:ObjectReference.Declaration="{dw:ObjectReference textBoxSource}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="YourStringProperty"
                 Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <x:Array Type="sys:Object">
                    <sys:Int16>1</sys:Int16>
                    <dw:ObjectReference Key="textBoxSource"/>
                </x:Array>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And then you could later access both the index and the `TextBox` in the ConvertBack method

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    object[] parameters = parameter as object[];
    short index = (short)parameters[0];
    object source = (parameters[1] as TextBox).DataContext;
    //...
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, but I am already using the `ConverterParameter` which Dr.WPF uses to hold the object

Comment: @tom: You can supply more then one value to `ConverterParameter` if you use e.g `<x:Array "sys:Object">`..

Comment: I don't know if I understand it right, but the `TextBox.Text` is what the `object value` holds. I need to get the original value from the binded dependency property (before it is converted using `Convert()` method and displayed by `TextBox`

Comment: @tom: You're right, sorry, I got mixed up. You should access the `DataContext` instead

Comment: Going through the [Dr.WPF instructions](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/02/supplying-an-object-reference-in-the-constructorparameters-collection-of-an-objectdataprovider/) I also realized, that I probably don't need that extension, because I want to get a value of a `DependencyProperty` so can't I just pass it somehow in the `ConvertParameter` using the `x:Array` as you suggested?

Comment: @tom: Unfortunately, you won't be able to bind the values in the x:Array but I added another way of getting the source value in the converter

Answer (score 1):

Would you be better off using an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) and a MultiBinding?

```
public interface IMultiValueConverter
{
    object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, look at: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings

Comment: This is actually opposite of what is needed: MultiBinding binds _several_ VM objects to a _single_ UI object, while the OP needs it other way round.

Comment: @Amittai No, `IMultiValueConverter` is not what I need, Vlad is right

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you really want to be able to edit the constituents,
you could represent your number by a more complex object which allows you to access its 4 constituent parts through an indexer. That way it's just a simple binding and the object that keeps the 4 parts is accessed and can piece together the whole number:

```
public class MyNumber {
  public int this[int index] {
    get { /**/ } set { /**/ }
  }
  public string FullNumber { get { /**/ } }
}

<TextBox Text={Binding MyNumber[0]}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just built up quick sample. Please check if you are looking for the same. This is working at my end.

- Xaml Code

  ```
  <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="1/2/3/4" x:Name="txtSource"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSource, 
                              Path=Text, 
                              Converter={StaticResource txtConv},
                              ConverterParameter='0'}" 
               x:Name="txtTarget1"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSource, 
                              Path=Text, 
                              Converter={StaticResource txtConv},
                              ConverterParameter='1'}"
               ></TextBox>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSource, 
                              Path=Text, 
                              Converter={StaticResource txtConv},
                              ConverterParameter='2'}" ></TextBox>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSource, 
                              Path=Text, 
                              Converter={StaticResource txtConv},
                              ConverterParameter='3'}"></TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- Code Behind

  ```
  public class TextConverter : IValueConverter {
      #region IValueConverter Members

      public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
          string input = (string)value;
          char[] sep = {'/'};
          string[] iparray = input.Split (sep);
          int index = Int32.Parse((string)parameter);

          return iparray[index];
      }

      public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
          throw new NotImplementedException ();
      }

      #endregion
  }
  ```

However, I couldn't understand the exact issue with `ConvertBack` method. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I am actually binding to property created in code behind which implements INofifyPropertyChanged interface and is generated by the wizard when adding LINQ to SQL classes. The problem is implementing the ConvertBack method, but I already marked the answer which I used (from Vlad)