# IValueConverter - Source and Converter in the same Binding/ Same Control using both the Source and Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a set of comboboxes and textboxes like this:

C1         T1

C2         T2

C3         T3

I implemented an IValueConverter to set the TimeZone in C1 and get the corresponding time in T1. Same for the other pairs.

**What I want to do is :** if a user manually changes the time in T1, the time in T2 and T3 must change corresponding to T1 as well as according to the TimeZone.

T1 is not the reference though. If any of the textboxes have their value changed, all other textboxes must change as well.

*This change can happen:*

1. If the TimeZone is changed in the Combobox
2. if the User manually changes the time by typing in the text box

**Here is my full code:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public static int num;
    public static bool isUserInteraction;
    public static DateTime timeAll;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

        this.DataContext = TimeZones;

        cmb_TZ1.SelectedIndex = 98;
        cmb_TZ2.SelectedIndex = 46;
        cmb_TZ3.SelectedIndex = 84;
        cmb_TZ4.SelectedIndex = 105;
        cmb_TZ5.SelectedIndex = 12;
    }

    private void ComboBox_Selection(object Sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
         {
        var cmbBox = Sender as ComboBox;

        DateTime currTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeZoneInfo tst = (TimeZoneInfo)cmbBox.SelectedItem;
        if (isUserInteraction)
        {
           /*  txt_Ctry1.Text=
              txt_Ctry2.Text =
              txt_Ctry3.Text =
              txt_Ctry4.Text =
              txt_Ctry5.Text =*/
            isUserInteraction = false;
        }
    }

  private void TextBox_Type(object Sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     var txtBox = Sender as TextBox;

        if (isUserInteraction)
        {
            timeAll = DateTime.Parse(txtBox.Text); 
            if (txtBox.Name != "txt_Ctry1")
             txt_Ctry1.Text=
                       if (txtBox.Name != "txt_Ctry2")
                txt_Ctry2.Text =
                       if (txtBox.Name != "txt_Ctry3")
                txt_Ctry3.Text =
                       if (txtBox.Name != "txt_Ctry4")
                txt_Ctry4.Text =
                       if (txtBox.Name != "txt_Ctry5")
                txt_Ctry5.Text =
            isUserInteraction = false;
        }
    }


    private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isUserInteraction = true;
    }
}
public class TimeZoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (MainWindow.isUserInteraction == false)
        {
            return value == null ? string.Empty : TimeZoneInfo
                .ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, (TimeZoneInfo)value)
                .ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
        }
 else
        {
            return value == null ? string.Empty : TimeZoneInfo
           .ConvertTime(MainWindow.timeAll, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, (TimeZoneInfo)value)
           .ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
        }

             }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

}

**XAML:**

```
   <Window x:Class="Basic_WorldClock.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Basic_WorldClock"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

  <Window.Resources>
  <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="timezone" ObjectType="{x:Type     
   sys:TimeZoneInfo}" MethodName="GetSystemTimeZones">
  </ObjectDataProvider>
      <local:TimeZoneConverter x:Key="timezoneconverter"/>
   </Window.Resources>

   <Grid Margin="0,0.909,0,-0.909">

    <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time1" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmb_TZ1, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource timezoneconverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time2"  Text="{Binding ElementName=cmb_TZ2, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource timezoneconverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time3" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmb_TZ3, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource timezoneconverter}}" Height="23.637" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selection" PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22.667" Margin="0,89.091,51.667,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144.666"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ2" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selection" PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22.667" Margin="0,131.091,52.667,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144.666"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ3" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selection" PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22.667" Margin="0,0,48.334,123.575" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="144.666"/>


</Grid>
```

**Question:** How can I cascade the corresponding changes to other text boxes by using the Convert method the same way the combox does?
I can use the TextChanged method to capture changes in the reference text box and I can add a few lines of code to make those changes, but I want to use the IValueConverter. Can I have the Source and Converter in the same binding for a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've got so far, it's difficult to provide precise information. But based on what you've described, it seems the main problem here is that you're not using the normal "view model"-based techniques that WPF is designed to be used with. In addition, you are binding the `Text` property to the time zone, rather than the time, so what WPF wants to update when the `Text` property changes is actually the combo box selection rather than the time itself.

The first thing you need to do is, instead of having your controls refer *to each other*, create a view model class that represents the actual state you want to display, and then use that for your `DataContext` in the window, binding appropriate properties to the particular controls.

And what are those appropriate properties? Well, based on your description you actually have just four: **1)** The actual time, and **2)** through **4)** the three time zones you want to handle.

So, something like this:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // The actual time. Similar to the "timeAll" field you have in the code now
    // Should be kept in UTC
    private DateTime _time;

    // The three selected TimeZoneInfo values for the combo boxes
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone1;
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone2;
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone3;

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _time, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone1
    {
        get { return _timeZone1; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone1, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone2
    {
        get { return _timeZone2; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone2, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone3
    {
        get { return _timeZone3; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone3, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void UpdateValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(People often encapsulate the `PropertyChanged` event and `UpdateValue()` method in a base class that can be reused for all your view model types.)

With that, then you write an implementation of `IMultiValueConverter` that takes as the input the combo box index (i.e. `Index1`, `Index2`, or `Index3` as appropriate) and the `Time` property value, uses those two values to produce the time-zone converted value for the text box, which is bound using those two values and the converter.

The converter's `Convert()` method will do the above conversion. Then you'll need to make the `ConvertBack()` method use the appropriate combo box value to convert back to the UTC time.

Unfortunately, there's a bit of a wrinkle here. Your converter will not normally have access to that value. The `IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack()` method only gets the bound target value, and is expected to convert back to the bound source values from that. It's not designed to allow you to update one source value based on another source value and the target value.

There are a number of ways around this limitation, but none that I know of are very elegant.

One option uses the view model exactly as I've shown above. The trick is that you'll need to pass via `ConverterParameter` a reference to the `ComboBox` associated with the bound `Text` property, so that the `ConvertBack()` method can use the currently selected value (you can't pass the currently selected value itself as the `ConverterParamater` value, because `ConverterParameter` is not a dependency property and so can't be the target of a property binding).

Done this way, you might have a converter that looks like this:

```
class TimeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public string Format { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime utc = (DateTime)values[0];
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = (TimeZoneInfo)values[1];

        return tzi != null ? TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, tzi).ToString(Format) : Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string timeText = (string)value;
        DateTime time;

        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(timeText, Format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
        {
            return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
        }

        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)parameter;
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = (TimeZoneInfo)comboBox.SelectedValue;

        return new object[] { TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, tzi, TimeZoneInfo.Utc), Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

And XAML that looks like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO38517212BindTimeZoneAndTime.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO38517212BindTimeZoneAndTime"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="timezone"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type s:TimeZoneInfo}"
                        MethodName="GetSystemTimeZones">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <l:TimeConverter x:Key="timeConverter" Format="HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy"/>
    <p:Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    </p:Style>
    <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    </p:Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone1}"/>
      <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource timeConverter}"
                        ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=comboBox1}"
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Time"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="comboBox1"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone2}"/>
      <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource timeConverter}"
                        ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=comboBox2}"
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Time"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="comboBox2"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox3" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone3}"/>
      <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource timeConverter}"
                        ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=comboBox3}"
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Time"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="comboBox3"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>      
</Window>
```

This will work fine at run-time. But you will get design-time _"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error messages, due to the use of `{x:Reference ...}` in the `ConverterParameter` assignments. To some, this is a minor inconvenience, but I find it a huge annoyance and am willing to go to a fair amount of effort to avoid it. :)

So, here's a completely different approach, which foregoes the converter altogether and puts all of the logic inside the view model itself:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ktimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy";

    // The actual time. Similar to the "timeAll" field you have in the code now
    // Should be kept in UTC
    private DateTime _time = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // The three selected TimeZoneInfo values for the combo boxes
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone1 = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone2 = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    private TimeZoneInfo _timeZone3 = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;

    // The text to display for each local time
    private string _localTime1;
    private string _localTime2;
    private string _localTime3;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _localTime1 = _localTime2 = _localTime3 = _time.ToString(_ktimeFormat);
    }

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _time, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone1
    {
        get { return _timeZone1; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone1, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone2
    {
        get { return _timeZone2; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone2, value); }
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone3
    {
        get { return _timeZone3; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _timeZone3, value); }
    }

    public string LocalTime1
    {
        get { return _localTime1; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _localTime1, value); }
    }

    public string LocalTime2
    {
        get { return _localTime2; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _localTime2, value); }
    }

    public string LocalTime3
    {
        get { return _localTime3; }
        set { UpdateValue(ref _localTime3, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void UpdateValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        switch (propertyName)
        {
        case "TimeZone1":
            LocalTime1 = Convert(TimeZone1);
            break;
        case "TimeZone2":
            LocalTime2 = Convert(TimeZone2);
            break;
        case "TimeZone3":
            LocalTime3 = Convert(TimeZone3);
            break;
        case "LocalTime1":
            TryUpdateTime(LocalTime1, TimeZone1);
            break;
        case "LocalTime2":
            TryUpdateTime(LocalTime2, TimeZone2);
            break;
        case "LocalTime3":
            TryUpdateTime(LocalTime3, TimeZone3);
            break;
        case "Time":
            LocalTime1 = Convert(TimeZone1);
            LocalTime2 = Convert(TimeZone2);
            LocalTime3 = Convert(TimeZone3);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void TryUpdateTime(string timeText, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        DateTime time;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(timeText, _ktimeFormat, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
        {
            Time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, timeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
        }
    }

    private string Convert(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Time, timeZone).ToString(_ktimeFormat);
    }
}
```

This version of the view model includes the formatted text values. Rather than using a converter to format, everything is done here in response to property change notifications that are being raised by the view model itself.

In this version, the view model does get a lot more complicated. But it's all very straightforward, easily understood code. And the XAML winds up a lot simpler:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO38517212BindTimeZoneAndTime.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO38517212BindTimeZoneAndTime"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="timezone"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type s:TimeZoneInfo}"
                        MethodName="GetSystemTimeZones">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <p:Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    </p:Style>
    <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    </p:Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>        
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone1}"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding LocalTime1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone2}"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding LocalTime2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox3" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" SelectedValue="{Binding TimeZone3}"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding LocalTime3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>      
</Window>
```

Either of these should directly address the issue you're asking about, i.e. allowing changes in one of multiple values that are derived from a single value being converted to be propagated back to the other values. But if neither of those suit you, you have a number of other options.

One of the most obvious is to simply subscribe to the appropriate property-changed events in each control and then explicitly copy back to the other controls the values you want. IMHO that would be *very* inelegant, but it wouldn't necessarily require the use of the view-model paradigm, and so it could be argued that would be more consistent with your original example.

Another approach would be to make your *converter* much more heavyweight, by making it inherit `DependencyObject` so that it can have a dependency property bound as the target of the time zone value. You would still need to also use the `IMultiBindingConverter` approach to set the target `Text` property, but this would allow for a less hacky way to make sure the time zone information is available in the `ConvertBack()`.

You can see an example of this approach in [this answer to Get the Source value in ConvertBack() method for IValueConverter implementation in WPF binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064764). Note that with this approach, each binding will require its own separate instance of the converter. No sharing as a resource.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to thank here but your code taught me a lot!! I am learning WPF as an interest and it has been quite tough going, been so close to giving up. Thank you for patiently explaining and sharing some cool coding techniques.

Comment: You're very welcome. I agree, the learning curve on WPF is steep. It is not helped by the fact that the WPF API itself offers multiple ways to do the same thing, and it's not always clear what the "right" way is. There's a lot of complexity and hidden rules that are hard to grasp. I'm glad the above helped you get past at least some of that. FWIW, while I'm not sure I qualify as a WPF expert, I have gotten past what I think is the steepest part of the learning curve; I encourage you to keep trying, as I've found that once you understand WPF, it actually offers some very nice features.