# MultiValueConverter object[] ConvertBack

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on converter, I am very new. I don't know, how to get the value from xaml binding. May be will write my code.

In my convertback code I am bit confused. For Double B, I need the value of B inXAML

```
<TextBlock Text="Offset X [px]"
           Style="{StaticResource StdTextBlockStyle}" />
    <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_1" 
             Style="{StaticResource StdTextBoxStyle}" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}">
                <Binding Path="B" />
                <Binding Path="A" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
   </TextBox>
<TextBlock />
```

//C# Code //

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       double B = (double)values[0];
       double A = (double)values[1];
       double C = A-B;
       return C;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {

            double C = (double)value;    
            double B = // I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET VALUE FOR B. B is from XAML// ???

            object[] ret = new object[1];    
            ret[0] = C + B;
            return ret;
```

Comment: what converter interface are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot add. I am using multiconverter

Comment: I guess value that you receive is A+C anyway ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064445/get-the-source-value-in-convertback-method-for-ivalueconverter-implementation) will asnwer your question.

Comment: yes I want C + A, But A is emty now, I have to fill

Comment: u r binding text, so A+C is concatenation, in convertback, just set the Value to A or C

Comment: is this your exact problem or have you simplified it for the case ? as I can see you don't need to split value in A and C if it already is concatinated

Comment: Sorry, I missed something and It confused a lot. I updated it

Comment: Note that your ConvertBack method should return an array of length 2 (same length as the input to Convert). The two values are passed back to the two Bindings in the MultiBinding. That said, it might by simpler to have an additional property in your view model that represents the converted value. Thus you would not have a converter at all. Implementing ConvertBack in a multi-value converter is often impossible, because the conversion made in Convert is not reversible.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand, that result in `ConvertBack` it is combination of

```
 double B = (double)values[0];
 double A = (double)values[1];
```

you defined in `Convert`.
The main idea of Conversion in `MultiValueConverter` is definition of your own logic how do you want to see these values. That means you need to define your logic to calculate this array.
According to your `Convert` function:

```
double C = A-B;
```

We have in `ConvertBack`:

```
double B=A-C;
double A=C+B;
```

We cannot calculate A and B to define

```
Array[] x = new []{ A, B };
```

Because we have here equalation with 2 unknown variables.
Sorry, I don't believe this expression is convertible back.